# How can I change directory on bash on Ubuntu on windows?

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I cannot change directory like this

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlATo.png]

I have a problem like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSobh.png]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and apply code formatting instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you're passing **two** arguments to `cd`. The `cd Ashikur Rahman` *(notice the space)* for most commands is something like two separate commands: `cd Ashikur; cd Rahman` *(in `cd` case 2-nd argument would be just ignored though)*.

You'd have to enclose the part with space into quotes, like:

```
$ cd "Ashikur Rahman"
```

Comment: or if you're lazy: `$ cd Ash*`